# jQuery dropdown menu does not work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm developing a web application and put the jQuery menu, I took the base of the menu on this site https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/ o Example 5, only that the dropdown menu does not work the dropdown items are not triggered by clicking on the Enter / Sign up, menu items already appear, rather than appear when clicking the Enter / Register

Error Menu

[image]

```
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-5" tabindex="1">
  <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Entre/Cadastre-se<span class="caret"></span>
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li class="conteudo_drop">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> Meus Pedidos</a>
    </li>
    <li class="conteudo_drop">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i> Meus Dados</a>
    </li>
    <li class="conteudo_drop">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-group"></i> Fale Conosco</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><button type="button" onclick="" class="btn_entrar" >Entrar</button> </a>
    </li>
    <li class="conteudo_drop">
      <a href="cadastro.jsp"> Cliente novo? Cadastre-se</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper-dropdown-5.active {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: #4cbeff;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-5.active:after {
  border-color: #82d1ff transparent;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-5.active .dropdown {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  max-height: 400px;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li {
  padding: 0 10px ;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e8ea;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li:last-of-type a {
  border: none;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li i {
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

 /* Hover state */

.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li:hover a {
  color: #57a9d9;
}


    /* Active state */

.wrapper-dropdown-5.active {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: #4cbeff;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-5.active:after {
  border-color: #82d1ff transparent;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-5.active .dropdown {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  max-height: 400px;
}

.conteudo_drop{
  color:#00008B !important;
}

.conteudo_drop a:hover{
  color: #A9A9A9 !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13pt;
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#dd{
    display:none;
}
```

button.js:

```
function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("dd").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Since, i could not completely understand the problem, I have provided a part of the solution. Please refer this:[page](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp)

Comment: ,the dropdown menu dissaper with display:none, but function with  document.getElementById("dd").classList.toggle("show"); dont work